# $\lim_{(x→∞)}(x(2\log(⁡Γ(\frac{2x}{4x+1}))-\log⁡π ))$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

$\lim_{(x\rightarrow ∞)}x(2\log(⁡Γ(\frac{2x}{4x+1}))-\log⁡π )$
I found this limit using L Hospital rule by taking x to the den. I am wondering if there u=ias any other solution

Comment: you could do it by finding the order of convergence of $\Gamma(\frac{2x}{4x+1})$

Comment: $2\log2⁡Γ(\frac{2x}{4x+1})-\log⁡\pi $ does not $\to 0.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Composing Taylor series is a good way to do it.

Consider
$$\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon \right)=\sqrt{\pi }+\sqrt{\pi } \,  \psi
   \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\epsilon+O\left(\epsilon ^2\right)$$ Now, make $\epsilon=-\frac{1}{2 (4 x+1)}$ and continue with Taylor expansion to get
$$\Gamma \left(\frac{2 x}{4 x+1}\right)=\sqrt{\pi }-\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \,\psi \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{8
   x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$
$$\log \left(\Gamma \left(\frac{2 x}{4 x+1}\right)\right)=\frac{\log (\pi )}{2}-\frac{\psi \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{8
   x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$